# POST requests for specific URL are taking 3 minutes

Tags: php, curl

All my POST-type requests for a specific URL in the server (production) are taking about 3 minutes to return the response, that is, a few seconds after I submit the form, I look at the API site and there are my data posted, but on my site the request is pending, after exactly 3 minutes it is finished returning the necessary data.

I think something is holding the response for 3 minutes because I tested the same code in the local environment and it worked quickly (it took about 10 seconds), what could be causing this "slowness"?

[image]

Look at a short snippet of my code, which works fine in the local environment, but it takes 3 minutes for production to return the API result.

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/';
    $this->curl = curl_init();
    $this->recvWindow = 60000;

    $curl_options = [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Binance PHP API Agent',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    ];

    curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $curl_options);
}

private function privateRequest($url, $params = [], $method = 'GET')
{
    $params['timestamp'] = number_format((microtime(true) * 1000), 0, '.', '');
    $params['recvWindow'] = $this->recvWindow;

    $query = http_build_query($params, '', '&');

    $sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $query, $this->secret);

    $headers = array(
        'X-MBX-APIKEY: ' . $this->key,
    );

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url . $url . "?{$query}&signature={$sign}");

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');

    if ($method == "POST") {
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array());
    }

    if($method == 'GET'){
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    }

    if ($method == 'DELETE') {
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    }


    //Get result
    $result = curl_exec($this->curl);

    if ($result === false) {
        throw new \Exception('CURL error: ' . curl_error($this->curl));
    }

    // Decode results
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    if (!is_array($result) || json_last_error()) {
        throw new \Exception('JSON decode Error');
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The curl does not generate any error because the API returns status 200 with the required data, the problem is that it takes 3 minutes to return the response.

Note: In other APIs the post works very well in production, returning the response in a maximum of 5 seconds.

Comment: Have you perhaps enabled Chrome's network throttling (last option in the _Network_ console toolbar)?

Comment: No, this option is disabled. I've tested in other browsers and it still takes 3 minutes to EXACT.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the timestamp and recvWindow in the params are for, but if you're using them to check for specific time windows, then I would make sure the server is configured with the correct timezone.